# Get XML feed from client IP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml

I need to integrate an XML feed from an external source, and one of the parameters I need to send to get the xml is IP.

When I use PHP, I send the server IP and it works fine. The problem is, that the XML is customized by the IP I send, so I need to actually send the clients IP. This poses a problem because the XML feed won't give me an answer if it detects that the source IP is different than the IP that I send.

Comment: Yes, but how do I send the client IP address? I need to use it, so that the IP is different per person.

Comment: Well, sorry for commenting the logic of the system. I've posted an answer.

Comment: @Meir: How do *you* send the IP address? Also please show the URL of the feed in your question so it is clear about which feed you ask.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now not sure I fully understand the problem but the only way to find out the public IP address of the computer that runs the browser is to read it from the server. You can then feed it to the JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var clientAddress = <? echo json_encode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); ?>;
//--></script>
```

Of course, this will break if the user has a proxy that changes he's IP address on each request.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I access an external url with javascript? That is cross site scripting...

Comment: That's an entirely different question. The jQuery site has comprehensive information about AJAX. Make sure you check that first.

Comment: I tried. Nothing worked for me. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: No, I would not do that to someone who is trying to help me... Upvoted

Comment: I'm not very familiar with cross-domain AJAX but I believe it requires certain arrangements that only the feed owner can do: either implementing JSONP response or using certain HTTP headers. Don't they have docs about it?

Comment: Not really. Thank you very much, I will wait for an answer from the owner of the feed.